# Change all href inside a DIV with class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change all href links inside a curtain DIV that uses a class.
So far I have been able change all links in a page using this snippet:

```
function Sl(){
 var l = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<l.length;i++){
   var cl = l[i].href;
     l[i].href = cl.replace(cl,'http://domain,com/'+cl);}
}
 window.onload = Sl;
```

but its not an ideal solution.

I have tried using this line:

`var l = getElementsByClassName('class').getElementsByTagName('a');`

but it didn't work.

---

**Note:** No Jquery solutions, JavaScript only thanks, I don't want to have to load jquery just for a small snippet.

Comment: Try `var l = document.querySelectorAll('.class a')`

Comment: You could also use the setAttribute method to change an elements specific attribute. For example:  l[i].setAttribute("href",'http://domain,com/'+cl);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) is a well supported method (even IE8 supports it), so you could use a simple selector to get all the `a` elements:

```
var l = document.querySelectorAll('div.class a');
```

---

> I have tried using this line:
>
> ```
> var l = getElementsByClassName('class').getElementsByTagName('a');
> ```
>
> but it didn't work

That's because, just like `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName` returns a **list of elements**. If you know that there is only one element with that class, you can directly reference it:

```
var l = getElementsByClassName('class')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Otherwise you have to iterate over the `.class` elements with a `for` loop and inside the loop call `getElementsByTagName('a')` to get the `a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please try the following code:**

```
var elements = document.getElementById('parentContainer').getElementsByClassName('classname');

   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
        //change href's here..
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: You can make your answer better by **explaining** what you did.